# gcc instrumentation - is it possible to automatically output the arguments of a function?

Tags: c++, gcc

I know about [`-finstrument-functions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html):

*Generate instrumentation calls for entry and exit to functions. Just after function entry and just before function exit, the following profiling functions are called with the address of the current function and its call site. (On some platforms, __builtin_return_address does not work beyond the current function, so the call site information may not be available to the profiling functions otherwise.)*

But this only outputs the adress of the function and caller and not any of the inputs or outputs of the function.

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *this_fn,
                               void *call_site);
void __cyg_profile_func_exit  (void *this_fn,
                               void *call_site);
```

I want to `cout <<` the arguments so I can do whitebox/integration testing: **testing the input and output of a set of functions along an execution path in response to an event.**

I know I could accomplish my desired instrumentation by running a Python script on my desired functions.

**QUESTION**

But is there a way to accomplish this instrumentation using only `gcc` options?

**THOUGHTS**

To accomplish this using only `gcc` and C++, I think I would need a way to loop over the function's arguments so I can call each object's `<<` operator.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` will give you a function name instead of an address.  Not good way of getting the args though.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to accomplish this instrumentation using only gcc options?

No.

The `-finstrument-functions` flag performs a pass over all defined functions, and inserts a bit of code into each one.

You want to extend that pass to "for each function, iterate over all of its arguments, and insert additional bit of code for each one".

I don't believe such functionality exists in GCC, so you'll have to build a custom GCC pass (not a trivial proposition).

In addition, "cout << arg" is not something a GCC pass could do -- your pass would have to figure out which of the many overloaded `cout::operator<<(...)` methods to call, and not every type can be streamed that way.

Comment: "you'll have to build a custom GCC pass (not a trivial proposition)". Not trivial perhaps, but it's not *that* hard to build a plugin.