# how to loop over function's arguments without variadic function

Tags: c++, gcc

Without using variadic function, is it possible to loop over a function's arguments?

This would help me in my question [gcc instrumentation - is it possible to automatically output the arguments of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169256/gcc-instrumentation-is-it-possible-to-automatically-output-the-arguments-of-a)

Comment: Why do you want to do it? What is the real underlying problem that you need to solve?

Comment: We do not have reflection so no, you can't loop through the parameters.  Forward to a variadic template to take an array.

Comment: But you *do* differ a variadic function from a variadic template function? You might achieve with the latter...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude to be able to make integration testing easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169256/gcc-instrumentation-is-it-possible-to-automatically-output-the-arguments-of-a

Comment: Theoretically this is possible by utilizing information about each parameter's location and type from the debug symbol table, but it's probably going to be complicated and slow as a dead slug. That might not matter for your use case, though. It would be interesting, I think, if someone had already done this.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I would be interested in this method as I don't have time-critical code; this would be used in debug-mode. Please flesh it out as an answer or a link.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have the time necessary to do the required research at this time, but I've got this question flagged and if no one else comes along I'll revisit it later, time permitting.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError what keywords, besides `GDB`, should I google? That’d be more than enough help.

Comment: Read up on DWARF and ELF file formats.

Comment: I googled a but, and it looks like [this guy](https://github.com/sandeepmukherjee/calltrace) has been doing something in the same vein. You might want to check it out. I have no personal experience with it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError he's just using `-finstrument` which doesn't give you access to the arguments. I guess I'll have to use scripts and `gdb`.

Comment: Ah, so he is - sorry to get your hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to output the parameters, a variadic template function could do the trick – offering the type safety a variadic function is lacking...

```
void print() { }

template <typename T, typename ... TT>
void print(T const& t, T const& ... tt)
{
    std::cout << t << ' ';
    print(tt...);
}

template <typename F, typename ... TT>
void execute(F f, TT&& ... tt)
{
    std::cout << "calling function with arguments: ";
    print(tt...);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    f(std::forward<TT>(tt)...);
}
```

Even more elegant, if C++17 is available, is a fold expression:

```
template <typename F, typename ... TT>
void execute(F f, TT&& ... tt)
{
    std::cout << "calling function with arguments: ";
    char const* comma = "";
    ((std::cout << comma << tt, comma = ", "), ...);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    f(std::forward<TT>(tt)...);
}
```

Note how here modifying the `comma` variable allows to separate the arguments in the output string by commas without adding a trailing one.

If you allow a bit of pre-compiler magic, we even could include the function name:

```
template <typename F, typename ... TT>
void execute_(F f, char const* name, TT&& ... tt)
{
    std::cout << "calling function '" << name << "' with arguments: ";
    // ...
}

#define execute(FUNCTION, ...) execute_(FUNCTION, #FUNCTION, ## __VA_ARGS__)
// be aware of GCC extension:                                ^^
// catching empty arguments list!

// alternative variant, not relying on extensions but requiring C++20:
#define execute(F, ...) execute_(F, #F __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Usage example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/asjd1YMe6) (including a `print` variant not relying on an empty base function: `print2`)...

It has a bit a taste of workaround (sure, <s>you need another function call and</s><sup>1</sup> lambdas might look ugly), but you get the result with pure C++ means and no ugly tricks – apart from the macro, obviously; given variant relies on a GCC extension.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Not any more with the fold expression.</sub>

Comment: Nice. One minor issue may be that you 'worker' function `execute_` (in the linked-to fulll snippet) calls both `print` explicitly (so not general) as well as the the passed in `f`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Not sure what you mean exactly. It's the nature of a recursive template to recurse down to the empty (non-template) base, be it function or struct. One might have dropped the empty function entirely in favour of some if-constexpr pattern, but then – to catch the empty case – we need to separate first and remaining arguments by other means like e.g. two lambdas as demonstrated [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3s6dhK94a). Nicer? Suppose that's a matter of taste. What actually is questionable is *forwarding* the arguments to `std::cout::operator<<` – the latter won't change them

Comment: anyway, so if actually even an *error* might be debated... What really is an improvement is a *fold expression*, demonstrated at the same link and which I have already added to the answer ;)